How 'secure' cookie attribute prevent XSS attack?
Can someone explain to me how secure flag (cookies) works? How can it prevent XSS? How can i make a demo lab to explain how secure flag work?
I tried creating a lab to test how the secure flag would protect cookies from XSS attacks but it didn't work.

Besides the question being off-topic, secure cookies don't prevent XSS, only ensures that the cookie is never sent over unencrypted channels.
